# Robocopy - Windows Permission (Access Denied even with Admin)

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I need to move files from a server to another remote server. I've created the batch script below to do this:

```
@echo off
NET USE \\remote server\IPC$ /U:domain\Account password
robocopy D:\location to get files from\ \\remote server to move files to\ /E /XA:H /R:5 /W:1 /MOV /LOG:C:\robocopybackup.log
NET USE \\remote server\IPC$ /D
```

The weird thing is when I connect with the Admin or my account directly on the remote server, I can create/modify and delete files, however when I map to the remote server from the server I need to move the files frome with the Admin or my account I get an "Access Denied" error.

I have checked the permissions and I definitely have the right permissions. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that although your NET USE command should authenticate your session, that you've not associated a drive mapping with the ROBOCOPY command. Try:
NET USE **D:** \remote server\IPC$ /U:domain\Account password
...so that the same drive you are using for the source during the copy has been mapped using the correct credentials.